# Waiting for a visible locator returns a non-clickable element

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

Together with my tech lead, we implemented this method:

```
def get_visible_locator(self, selector):
        locators = self.page.query_selector_all(selector)
        for locator in locators:
            if locator.is_visible():
                return locator
        else:
            raise Exception('Can not find visible object with given selector:'
                            f' {selector}')
```

Calling the method sometimes fails:

```
self.get_visible_locator('text="Select All"').click(timeout=1000)
```

One workaround is using sleep of 2 seconds before calling the method, but my tech lead doesn't like this.

How to return the first visible and clickable / enabled element?

Comment: ElementHandles (query_selector_all) are discouraged, we recommend Locators instead which do the visible check etc. all out of the box: https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locator-vs-elementhandle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The misconception here seems to be that `visible == clickable`. That is not the case. In fact the docs explain what exact [actionability checks](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/actionability) are performed that determines whether the element is clickable

> For example, for page.click(selector, **kwargs), Playwright will
> ensure that:
>
> element is Attached to the DOM
>
> element is Visible
>
> element is Stable, as in not animating or completed animation
>
> element Receives Events, as in not obscured by other elements
>
> element is Enabled

Functionality to check whether all this is True for any element is currently not exposed in playwright (specifically, for checking whether the element is stable and reactive). The best you can do is change `if locator.is_visible()` to `if locator.is_visible() and locator.is_enabled()` to additionally check whether it is enabled as well (which would be done as part of the actionability checks later).

You can track the relevant issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2353)